# Laravel Octane with Rabbitmq - broken pipe or closed connection error and CHANNEL_ERROR - expected 'channel.open'(60, 40)

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, laravel-octane

- Laravel version: "^8.54"
- Octane version: "^1.0",
- RabbitMQ version: "3.8.6"
- Package (vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) version: "^11.3"

While pushing the event data to RabbitMQ via using `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq` package, I am getting these two errors:

- **CHANNEL_ERROR - expected 'channel.open'(60, 40)** -- getting this error mostly
- **broken pipe or closed connection** -- sometimes this error pops up

Weirdly, this error occurs every other times. And, when getting success, the queue data are getting lost even though it does not provide any error (not available in rabbitmq queue).

This scenario is happening after a certain time of app deployment, that means - this issue is not happening all the time. After a certain period (exactly not sure how much) of time, these errors are popping up.

Does anybody face similar kind of issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Laravel version 9
- Octane version 1
- Rabbitmq version 3.11.8
- Package version 13.1

I had the same issue till now but I managed a solution for it and I wanted to share it here so it can be a reference for anyone will have the same issue.

**Describe Bug**
The bug originally is from how to handle rabbitmq connection with octane because Laravel octane is based on stateful requests not stateless like php fpm which is used by Laravel without octane when octane server starts it creates original app container after that each request sent this octane app create another **clone of the original app container** so what happens that while octane server is always up and when a rabbitmq connection is down what happens that the original container can't resolves the connection because it's down and can not create a new connection so it makes show this error that the server can not open channel cause the connection was close.

**Solution**

- first we need to make sure that every clone that handles request from original app container in octane creates new connection with rabbitmq to make sure even if there is no connection there will be new one connected so to do this we need to reconfigure `QueueSerivceProvider.php` class that is originally created in Laravel and here is a copy from it

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\DeferrableProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\BeanstalkdConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\DatabaseConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\NullConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\RedisConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SqsConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Connectors\SyncConnector;
use Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DatabaseFailedJobProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DatabaseUuidFailedJobProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DynamoDbFailedJobProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Failed\NullFailedJobProvider;
use Illuminate\Queue\Listener;
use Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers;
use Illuminate\Queue\Worker;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\SerializableClosure\SerializableClosure;
use VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Connectors\RabbitMQConnector;

class QueueServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    use SerializesAndRestoresModelIdentifiers;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->configureSerializableClosureUses();

        $this->registerManager();
        $this->registerConnection();
        $this->registerWorker();
        $this->registerListener();
        $this->registerFailedJobServices();
    }

    /**
     * Configure serializable closures uses.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureSerializableClosureUses()
    {
        SerializableClosure::transformUseVariablesUsing(function ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->getSerializedPropertyValue($value);
            }

            return $data;
        });

        SerializableClosure::resolveUseVariablesUsing(function ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->getRestoredPropertyValue($value);
            }

            return $data;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the queue manager.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerManager()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('queue', function ($app) {
            // Once we have an instance of the queue manager, we will register the various
            // resolvers for the queue connectors. These connectors are responsible for
            // creating the classes that accept queue configs and instantiate queues.
            return tap(new QueueManager($app), function ($manager) {
                $this->registerConnectors($manager);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the default queue connection binding.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerConnection()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('queue.connection', function ($app) {
            return $app['queue']->connection();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the connectors on the queue manager.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    public function registerConnectors($manager)
    {
        foreach (['Null', 'Sync', 'Database', 'Redis', 'Beanstalkd', 'Sqs', 'Rabbitmq'] as $connector) {
            $this->{"register{$connector}Connector"}($manager);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the Sync queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerRabbitmqConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('rabbitmq', function () {
            return new RabbitMQConnector($this->app['events']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Null queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerNullConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('null', function () {
            return new NullConnector;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Sync queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerSyncConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('sync', function () {
            return new SyncConnector;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the database queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerDatabaseConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('database', function () {
            return new DatabaseConnector($this->app['db']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Redis queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerRedisConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('redis', function () {
            return new RedisConnector($this->app['redis']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Beanstalkd queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerBeanstalkdConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('beanstalkd', function () {
            return new BeanstalkdConnector;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the Amazon SQS queue connector.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager $manager
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerSqsConnector($manager)
    {
        $manager->addConnector('sqs', function () {
            return new SqsConnector;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the queue worker.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerWorker()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('queue.worker', function ($app) {
            $isDownForMaintenance = function () {
                return $this->app->isDownForMaintenance();
            };

            $resetScope = function () use ($app) {
                if (method_exists($app['log']->driver(), 'withoutContext')) {
                    $app['log']->withoutContext();
                }

                if (method_exists($app['db'], 'getConnections')) {
                    foreach ($app['db']->getConnections() as $connection) {
                        $connection->resetTotalQueryDuration();
                        $connection->allowQueryDurationHandlersToRunAgain();
                    }
                }

                $app->forgetScopedInstances();

                return Facade::clearResolvedInstances();
            };

            return new Worker(
                $app['queue'],
                $app['events'],
                $app[ExceptionHandler::class],
                $isDownForMaintenance,
                $resetScope
            );
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the queue listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerListener()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('queue.listener', function ($app) {
            return new Listener($app->basePath());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the failed job services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerFailedJobServices()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('queue.failer', function ($app) {
            $config = $app['config']['queue.failed'];

            if (array_key_exists('driver', $config) &&
                (is_null($config['driver']) || $config['driver'] === 'null')) {
                return new NullFailedJobProvider;
            }

            if (isset($config['driver']) && $config['driver'] === 'dynamodb') {
                return $this->dynamoFailedJobProvider($config);
            } elseif (isset($config['driver']) && $config['driver'] === 'database-uuids') {
                return $this->databaseUuidFailedJobProvider($config);
            } elseif (isset($config['table'])) {
                return $this->databaseFailedJobProvider($config);
            } else {
                return new NullFailedJobProvider;
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a new database failed job provider.
     *
     * @param array $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DatabaseFailedJobProvider
     */
    protected function databaseFailedJobProvider($config)
    {
        return new DatabaseFailedJobProvider(
            $this->app['db'], $config['database'], $config['table']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new database failed job provider that uses UUIDs as IDs.
     *
     * @param array $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DatabaseUuidFailedJobProvider
     */
    protected function databaseUuidFailedJobProvider($config)
    {
        return new DatabaseUuidFailedJobProvider(
            $this->app['db'], $config['database'], $config['table']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new DynamoDb failed job provider.
     *
     * @param array $config
     * @return \Illuminate\Queue\Failed\DynamoDbFailedJobProvider
     */
    protected function dynamoFailedJobProvider($config)
    {
        $dynamoConfig = [
            'region' => $config['region'],
            'version' => 'latest',
            'endpoint' => $config['endpoint'] ?? null,
        ];

        if (!empty($config['key']) && !empty($config['secret'])) {
            $dynamoConfig['credentials'] = Arr::only(
                $config, ['key', 'secret', 'token']
            );
        }

        return new DynamoDbFailedJobProvider(
            new DynamoDbClient($dynamoConfig),
            $this->app['config']['app.name'],
            $config['table']
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [
            'queue',
            'queue.connection',
            'queue.failer',
            'queue.listener',
            'queue.worker',
        ];
    }
}
```

here we can see that I configured rabbitmq as one of the connectors in Laravel so it can be made as a singleton to create a new connection every time a replica is created to serve a request.

- second step we need to add `QueueServiceProvider.php` class in `app.php` under application service provider section

```
'providers' => [
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
//        App\Providers\HorizonServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
//        App\Providers\TelescopeServiceProvider::class,
]
```

- the final step is to close the replica connection after each request is terminated and we will add a listener `DisconnectedFromRabbit.php` class inside `octane.php` and we need to add in flush array inside `octane.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

class DisconnectedFromRabbit
{
    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param object $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle($event)
    {
        $event->app->make('queue')->connection()->close();
    }
}
```

```
'listeners' => [
    RequestTerminated::class => [
            // FlushUploadedFiles::class,
            App\Listeners\DisconnectedFromRabbit::class
        ],

        TaskReceived::class => [
            ...Octane::prepareApplicationForNextOperation(),
            //
        ],

        TaskTerminated::class => [
            App\Listeners\DisconnectedFromRabbit::class,
        ],
],

'flush' => [
        'queue',
    ],
```

Comment: a little clarification that there is now a merge request that should handle this bug in a more prober way but this is just a temp solution for it